# How can we improve Insert and updates in Oracle Exadata?

Tags: database, sql-update, sql-insert, exadata

Insert and update queries are taking long time as compared to select queries. 
Here are some stats for the table -

Table is storing monthly data. For current month it is MTD. The data for current month is getting deleted and loaded every day.

Daily insert row count - 2.5 millions, 
Daily delete time taken - less than one minute, 
Table has 13 months of data, 
Time taken to insert 2.5 millions rows  - 2 hrs 20 minutes, 
Time take to select records for a month - less than a minute

The tool used for insertion of data is Informatica Power center. The Informatica is using query push down to DB approach.

Please suggest on how I can reduce time of insertion for data in table at database level.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like informatica is doing row by row processing. Ideally a direct path parallel loading approach should be used. 2.5 million rows should load in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

usual strategy for speeding up inserts is to drop indexes as presql, use bulk load strategy and then recreate indexes after load completes